# errorexception trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, relation

[image]

As You can see after dd()

I am getting an object of "Note Category".

```
$note->category->name
```

it returns an error called trying to get property of non-object

[image]

Comment: Please share how are you fetching your note model

Comment: Where/what do you `dd()`? Is that a `$note` in your `foreach`? (Note that `relations` is empty)

Comment: @Luciano
`<tbody id="tbl_person_notes">
@php
$person = \Modules\Person\Entities\Person::with('notes.category')->find($person->id);
@endphp 
@include('person::profile.note-list', ['notes' => $person->notes])
</tbody>
`

Comment: @brombeer

Inside the foreach loop
`dd($note->category)`

Comment: `dd()` will stop execution, so you'd only get the dump for the first item in your loop. Try `dump(...)` instead, which will dump the same data as `dd()` but continue execution. There might be a note in there that doesn't have a category

Comment: @brombeer

Thank you so much, Just added Null Cohlesing Operator and found that there was empty relation and that's why it was triggering the error!

again thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd()` will stop execution, so you'd only get the dump for the first item in your loop. Try `dump(...)` instead, which will dump the same data as `dd()` but continue execution. There most likely is a note in your loop that doesn't have a category.